# Use of "B defers to A" when A takes precedence over B

Tags: single-word-requests

If A takes precedence over B, is it correct to say *B defers to A*? I searched the web for `precedence antonym` but found nothing useful.

Comment: +1 for telling the community what you've researched already.

Comment: You could also say "deigns" as in B deigns to A, or in a technical sense, B is overriden by A.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd need some context.  For example in some programming languages we might say that the multiplication operator takes precedence over the addition operator but I would not expect someone to say that addition *defers to* multiplication.

In something like seating arrangements for a formal event then, yes, *defers to* would be correct.

Answer (score 3):

You could say **is subordinate to:** B is subordinate to A. But it does rather depend on context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *defers* would be correct in most circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on whether B can actively decide to defer to A. The word *defer* means to submit to another's wishes, opinion, or governance usually out of respect. Just because A takes precedence, doesn't mean that B deferred to A. I wouldn't use the word *defer* unless A and B are people. Could you say *A supersedes B* instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could also say in a technical sense, B is overriden by A. (Although some would argue that "override" has a discrete Object-Oriented definition, but guess what - it means that is B and A are both potentially candidates, but A is used, because it overrides B!)

Defer is a fully valid word choice here, but both defer tends to have servant-like connotations.

Comment: I'm dubious of "deigns".  I would only use it in the form "A deigns to do b"

Comment: *deign* doesn't mean this in British English. It means "condescends" and is only used with an action: "B deigns to speak to me".

Comment: @Wudang I would deign to your authority on that, except I don't think that's accurate. :)  (Sorry, that's just the expression that I hear in American English... but I think Andrew Leach is right in re: British English

Comment: @AffableGeek.  Sorry, maybe my google-fu is weak but I can't find any usage of deign as a synonym for defer.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll scratch deign. It could just be a colloquialism I'm used to.

Comment: @Affable Geek: If you're saying you think you can grammatically *deign to someone's authority* I suggest that's a highly-localised "colloquialism" in your particular speech community. Google Books records not a single relevant instance of *"deign to your [anything]"* or *"deign to his [anything]"*, where [anything] is anything you could conceivably **defer** to. And between both those searches I only had to look at 9 entries in total anyway.